# CSS: Multiple Content in one div?

Tags: css, html, css-float

Is there a way to have one container div that I can put links on the left side and simple text on the right side?  I know this can be done, but I've been struggling to get it to work.  The code CSS I have would have to be highly modified due to the content I'm serving, so, I've uploaded a moc draft of what I want and see if you guys can help me out.

[image: MOC Draft]

Comment: `float: left` and `float: right` are already perfectly correct. Just note that the right floated content needs to come before the left floated one

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the note on the right floated content coming before the left really helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div id="menu">
  <div id="text" style="float:right;width:50%;text-align:right">text</div>
  <div id="links" style="float:left;width:50%">links</div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Make sure you have that clearing div and the two sides don't touch. Also, as Pekka points out the right content should come first or it will sit below the left.

Comment: I'm curious, why would the right content sit below the left if it didn't come first? It seems like it would still be on the right.

Comment: It would sit to the right, however, it would sit lower down by about 20px. I still haven't figured out exactly WHY this happens, just that it does.

Comment: i think it treats the floated left content as occupying 1 text line (ie, the gap is line-height pixels high). I don't know why that is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Quick and simple solution.  I haven't redesigned my site or done any heavy CSS stuff in about a year and a half, so getting back into it is a bit rough.  Also, I had it correct in the beginning, I guess, but forgot that float elements require a width set (duh me...).  So, after fixing that, I noticed another piece of CSS that was throwing my stuff off.  Everything is fixed now and works GREAT!  Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

I think Pekka is correct is saying `float:left` and `float:right` are generally the best way to go about tackling this sort of problem.

However, I find that I get a bit more control if I actually float all of the elements `left` (if you are writing for a language that's read left-to-right), and then let the elements stack on top of each other. That way you can specify margins, padding, and so on, and get exactly the sort of spacing you want.

To start a new line, you can do one of two things (or maybe even more!):

You can set `display: block`, or you can constrain the width of the container for the links/text such that the next element is forced to wrap around.

Hope that helps!